# bootstrap button and dropdown place inline and short the width of dropdown

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

My Code:

```
<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block mt-1">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnSearch"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>Search</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary ml-1" id="btnReset"><i class="fa fa-retweet fa-fw"></i>Reset</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success ml-1" id="btnExport"><i class="fas fa-file-export"></i>Export List</button>
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Download Format">
                    <option selected>Please select format</option>
                    <option value="1">Excel</option>
                    <option value="2">PDF</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Before adding the select element, the three buttons will keep inline and will look perfect. However, when I add the select element, this element will auto-put into the next line which makes  the select width too long

How do I put these four elements together in one line and shorten the selected element like this?

> [Search] [Reset] [Export] [Please select format        ]

The element will not have a form tag at parent.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.form-select` has css `display:block;width:100%`, so `select` will always be wrapped to next line.

This will work

```
<select class="form-select d-inline-block w-auto" style="vertical-align:middle"...
```

Or

```
<select class="form-select d-inline-block w-auto btn-group-vertical"...
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. but the select element position seem little bit higher than button, any solution for that?

Comment: Add `vertical-align`, I edited my ansewer.

Comment: FYI bootstrap 5 has the [`align-middle`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/vertical-align/) class for the `vertical-align: middle` style